# Get percentage distribution of list items in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a table with 3 columns as such:

| ID | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 10 |
| 2 | Mary | 20 |
| 3 | John | 10 |
| 4 | John | 1 |
| 5 | Mary | 8 |
| 6 | Tom | 12 |

How can I make a list that gives me the percentage distribution of the values above like so in Google Sheets:

| Name | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| John | 35% |
| Mary | 46% |
| Tom | 19% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=ArrayFormula({"Name","Percentage";VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>"")),{B2:B,ROUND(SUMIF(IF(ROW(B2:B),B2:B),B2:B,C2:C)/SUM(C2:C),2)},{1,2},FALSE)})`

Format the second column as percentage (**Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format > 0%**).

You'll notice the inclusion of three sets of curly brackets: {  }. Each contains the formation of some kind of virtual array within the overall `ArrayFormula` wrap.

The first set of curly brackets places headers side by side (as denoted by the comma) with the results underneath (as denoted by the semicolon).

A `VLOOKUP` makes up the results underneath.

`UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))` is what will be looked up. This forms a vertical list of all unique, non-blank entries in Column B (i.e., your names).

Each element of the above list is looked up within a virtual array composed of all elements of B2:B beside a second column of the `SUM` of C2:C per name divided by the overall `SUM` of C2:C, `ROUND`ed to two decimal places.

From the above virtual array, the results from both the first and second columns will be returned: {1,2}.

And `FALSE` means that the results are not in order and that an exact match should be located for each name.

Comment: Great. And thanks for marking my solution as "Best Answer." This helps the forum stay efficient by letting other contributors know at a glance from the home page that this issue is resolved; and it helps future site visitors more quickly find answers that match their own needs.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try this:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({B2:B,C2:C,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B),1,SUM(C2:C),0)},"select Col1,SUM(Col2),Col3 where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col3",0),"select Col1,Col2/Col3 label Col1'Name',Col2/Col3'Percentage'",1)
```

The Sequence() just creates a column of all the same value, namely the sum of column C.
The internal query aggregates the column C values by Name.
The external query divides those sums by the total sum.